# I have problem in my layout which i need that in bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm using Linear Layout as Parent layout and need a linear layout in the bottom of the page that i'll be using as a button.

All that i can use now is margin top to that linear layout which won't be the proper method. So i need help in implementing the layout to the bottom of the screen.

Or any recommendation of which layout that i need to use for the desired results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#F0F0F0">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Customer contact details:"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Name:"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="User Name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Email:"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="user@gmail.com"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Mobile:"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="123456"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="DELIVERY TYPE"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:text="Note: Delivery fee will be added based on the delivery 
address."
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="Pickup"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pickup_time"
        android:text="Select pickup time"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#D3D3D3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Delivery"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/delivery_time"
        android:text="Select delivery time"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/payment_option"
    android:text="PAYMENT OPTION"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Pay Online"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="DELIVERY ADDRESS"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/add_address"
    android:text="Add Address"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/button_red"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Home"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:text="User Address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#E22028">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use constraintlayout as root layout and constrain the layout with the button to the bottom of its parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for such complex view you should always go for constraint layout . They are really handy .

There are few things which you need to take care of , as from your code i can see lots of hard coded text and dimens , which turns out to be bad practice for any android developer . And even the naming conventions should be  take a look on .

Here  the guideline for naming convention we should follow for a long run in android . 
https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/project_and_code_guidelines.md

And for the constraint layout , you can use the below link to get better understanding.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html
https://blog.mindorks.com/android-constraint-layout

Always try to put your dimes in dimes.xml folder under res . Res < values < dimens.

Now coming to your questions , we can do this with constraint layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/constraint_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#F0F0F0"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_customer_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/constraint_parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/constraint_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/constraint_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Customer contact details:"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Name:"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="User Name" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Email:"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="user@gmail.com" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Mobile:"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="123456" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_delivery_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:text="DELIVERY TYPE"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/constraint_parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/constraint_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear_customer_detail" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_delivery_note"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:text="Note: Delivery fee will be added based on the delivery
    address."
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/text_delivery_type"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text_delivery_type"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_delivery_type" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_pickup_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/constraint_parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/constraint_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_delivery_note">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="Pickup"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/pickup_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Select pickup time"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#D3D3D3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Delivery"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/delivery_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Select delivery time"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/payment_option"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="PAYMENT OPTION"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/text_delivery_type"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text_delivery_type"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear_pickup_view" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_pay_online"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/constraint_parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/constraint_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/payment_option">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="Pay Online" />

</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="DELIVERY ADDRESS"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/add_address"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text_delivery_type"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/add_address" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_red"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Add Address"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/text_delivery_type"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear_pay_online" />


<View
    android:id="@+id/view_divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/constraint_parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/constraint_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/add_address" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_home"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Home"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/text_delivery_type"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text_delivery_type"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_divider" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_user_address"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="User Address"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/text_home"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/text_home"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_home" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#E22028"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will be helpful . Happy coding .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *Spacer* view inside your `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#F0F0F0">

  <!-- Top View -->
  <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <!-- Vertical Spacer -->
  <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

  <!-- Bottom View -->
  <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The vertical spacer will fill the screen between your top and bottom views.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F0F0F0">

    <!-- You can also use a button with 'android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp" -->
    <!-- instead of this LinearLayout'-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#E22028"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Continue"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/layout_bottom_btn"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F0F0F0"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Customer contact details:"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <TableLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:weightSum="2">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Name:"
                                android:textColor="#000000" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="User Name" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:weightSum="2">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Email:"
                                android:textColor="#000000" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="user@gmail.com" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:weightSum="2">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Mobile:"
                                android:textColor="#000000" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="123456" />
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="DELIVERY TYPE"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:text="Note: Delivery fee will be added based on the deliveryaddress."
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:text="Pickup"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pickup_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Select pickup time"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#D3D3D3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Delivery"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/delivery_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Select delivery time"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/payment_option"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="PAYMENT OPTION"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">

                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:text="Pay Online" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="DELIVERY ADDRESS"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/add_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_red"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Add Address"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:text="User Address"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I used `RelativeLayout` as parent in your layout and as Tim Castelijns commented, yes you have to use `ConstraintLayout` for better and responsive user interface.

Answer (score 0):

your layout has toomany hierarchy element , use constraint layout instead, however in LinearLayout you can add view with weight 1 and height 0 like i added in your layout

```
**<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#F0F0F0">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Customer contact details:"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Name:"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="User Name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Email:"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="user@gmail.com"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Mobile:"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="123456"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="DELIVERY TYPE"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:text="Note: Delivery fee will be added based on the delivery 
    address."
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="Pickup"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pickup_time"
        android:text="Select pickup time"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#D3D3D3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Delivery"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/delivery_time"
        android:text="Select delivery time"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/payment_option"
    android:text="PAYMENT OPTION"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Pay Online"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="DELIVERY ADDRESS"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/add_address"
        android:text="Add Address"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/button_red"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Home"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:text="User Address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#E22028">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>**
```

Answer (score 0):

replace LinearLayout with relative layout and create sub-parent linear layout and put your views inside it and then make it alignparent bottom make sure you have gave sub-parent layout height to wrap content

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--put your layout inside it-->

</LinearLayout>
```